# The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sylius.user_provider.name_or_email"

Tags: symfony, sylius

I just installed a copy of Sylius (built on Symfony2), and am trying to update composer to get it working. When I run **composer update**, it tries to clear the cache:

> An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'"
>   command:

This is when it hits the error:

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]
>
> ```
> The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sylius.user_provider.name_or_email".
> ```

I've seen similar errors related to "security.user.provider.concrete.fos_userbundle", but I can't seem to find any help on "sylius.user_provider.name_or_email".

This is a fresh install of the newest version of Sylius, so I'm not sure why it's having trouble finding the dependancy.

**edit**: I saw some suggestions that the cache clear needs to be run in the same directory as the site (which is where I'm running the composer update from), but I still tried running this as its own command:

```
cache:clear --no-warmup
```

From within the root dir of the Sylius install, to no avail. It throws the same error as above.

Comment: They have installation instructions on their page https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius#quick-installation

Comment: I followed these to the T. Updating composer was an attempt to resolve the same error being throw by this part of their instructions:

php app/console sylius:install

Comment: Well, report an issue then https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues

Comment: When I run php app/console sylius:install I get: [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException]                                                      
  The service "security.authentication.manager" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sylius.user_provider.name_or_email".

Comment: Give me a second to try it here though.

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate the help! I've got an issue open here: https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/5796  But will close it if you have any success.

Comment: Not reproducible for me, I could run `php app/console sylius:install` and it started the configuration steps successfully.

Comment: Curious, it appears that when I ran this: **php composer.phar create-project -s dev sylius/sylius-standard somefolder** (as documented here: http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/book/installation.html)  I got the issue as reported.  However, when I installed using **php composer.phar create-project sylius/sylius** it worked as expected. I'm not sure if this was the result of the folder, or of the -s dev option. Either way, I'm getting database errors now, so I know I'm making progress, and seem to be pas this issue, as I saw it clear the cache successfully this time. Thanks!